# Maven resource not found

Tags: java, maven

I want to include a text file in a maven project. The code itself compiles, but everytime I try to run it, whether in VS Code or at Command Line, I get: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: The provided file path /lightdm-forum.txt does not exist.` The file is located at src/main/resources/, which is the default.

Code Snippet:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment();

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> dataStream = env
                .readTextFile("/lightdm-forum.txt")
                .flatMap(new Splitter())
                .keyBy(0)
                .sum(1);

        dataStream.print();

        env.execute("Socket Stream WordCount");
    }
```

Maven seems to recognize the file and copies it to the  classpath root:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ WordCount_Stream ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
```

After compiling, the structure in the target folder looks like this:

```
.
├── classes
│   ├── com
│   │   └── lmu
│   │       └── WordCount_Stream
│   │           ├── WordCounter$Splitter.class
│   │           └── WordCounter.class
│   └── lightdm-forum.txt
```

So the file has been copied, but it is not found when I try to run the project.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You use `/lightdm-forum.txt` which is a path as global path. May you try to use a relative path like `path/to/your/subfolder/or/file` or `../path/to/upper/folder/and/other/folders`.

Maybe a better solution could be the usage of a classloader like `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourceName)` . With that you will be able to load files from maven resource package (src/Main/resources by default, Van be also customized in pom.xml)

Hope it helps!